# SUMIFS a specific YEAR

Tags: excel

Could you help me to fix this excel error?

I'm trying to write a SUMIFS function. On my first page I have all my banking transaction sorted by date from 2011 to 2014. All transactions belong to one and only one category.

I need to sum my value in Sum_range only if my two criteria are true.

1. The year of the date should be the year specified in a cell
2. The category should be the category specified in another cell

I know the problem is about the year or the date because I can sum with my second condition only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `SUMPRODUCT` can use `YEAR` like this,

`=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR('Transactions LU'!A:A)=A12)*('Transactions LU'!J:J=C11), 'Transactions LU'!H:H)`

... you won't want to use full column references (slower) and `SUMPRODUCT` can easily break trying to perform math on an extra text value. `SUMIFS` is vastly more efficient and in the area of 30% of the calculation load.

`=SUMIFS('Transactions LU'!H:H, 'Transactions LU'!A:A, ">="&DATE(A12, 1, 1), 'Transactions LU'!A:A, "<"&DATE(A12 +1, 1, 1), 'Transactions LU'!J:J, C11)`

The second `SUMIFS` formula is much preferred.

Comment: plus one, but I'd make one small change to the `SUMIFS` version. To accommodate the possibility that the date range also includes times I would change the second "date" criterion to "<"&DATE(A12+1,1,1) - otherwise if times are included you might exclude some values from 31st December

Comment: Good point and one I should have used. I've modified my suggested formula to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't 100% understand the issue - but if it is really only the Year column that is making trouble try using `Value(A12)` or if that doesn't work `TEXT(A12;0)` this either converts the value to text or into number format. It depends whether your data column is in number or text format. (probably try TEXT first).